# Probability on dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An unbiased die with numbers 1,2,3,4,,6,8  on it's six faces is rolled .After this roll,if an odd number apperars on the top face,all odd numbers on the die are doubled.If an even number appears on the top face,all even natural numbers are hlaved .If the giveen die changes in this way ,then the probability that the face 2 will appear on second roll ,is

My Attempt- (E 1)-Odd number appears on the top face

```
        (E  2)-Even number appears on the face
       ( A   )-2 appears on the second roll
```

P(E1)-2/6
P(E2)-4/6

P(A/E1)-2/6 AND P(A/E2)-1/6

Therefore required probability P(A)=P(E1)XP(A/E1)+P(E2)XP(A/E2)
                                    =2/9

I just randomly thought of using total probability theorem to solve it and it indeed solve it but I didn't understand the reasons for it's working.Can anyone explain this to me how should I identify when to use this theorem in context with this example if possible.Also is sample space required for analysing it?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: it's very long ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 2 cases. First is odd no. appears on first trial and 2 appears next or even no. appears on first trial and 2 appears later

So,

Case A: Odd no. appears first

P(A)=$ \frac{2}{6}$

Now, odd no.s are doubled. So, there are now totally two 2's on the dice.
So, P(E/A)=$ \frac{2}{6}$

So, since both events are correlated. P(E)=P(A)*P(E/A)=$ \frac{4}{36}$

Case B: Even no. appears first

P(B)=$ \frac{4}{6}$

Halve all even no.s. There is only one 2 now. So, P(E/B)=$ \frac{1}{6}$

So, since both events are correlated. P(E)=P(B)*P(E/B)=$ \frac{4}{36}$

So, net probability=$ \frac{4}{36}+ \frac{4}{36}=\frac{2}{9}$

It's just the problem of conditional probability. You're right.

Comment: do we need sample space for solving these question or is it a distraction\

Comment: You do need to know the entire sample space and the conditions where you'll get the favourable outcomes

Comment: what is the sample space for this

Comment: The sample space would be 36